# almost done with script to load images with Ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a script to load an image (1 - 5) and when it's loaded it's going to change the source of the current image. A loading spinner is visible while the image is loading. But the script is not ready yet and I need some help to complete it. Help and guidelines are appreciated!

I'm not sure how I should handle the `URL` and to get the new image to appear? With jQuery `.html(<img src.....` ? And I'm not sure how to change the `src` of the current image. Perhaps I'm on the wrong track and if there is a better way to solve this, I appreciate some suggestions on how I can alter the code.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var res = {
loader: $('<div />', {class: 'loader'}),
container: $('.galleryContainer')
}

var img = $("#mainImage");

$("#menu ul li a").click(function() {

var btnNum = $("a").index(this);
var imgFile = "images/bella-sky-hotel-" + btnNum + ".jpg";

$.ajax({
    url: ??,
    beforeSend: function() {
        res.container.append(res.loader);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // Change src of current image
        mainImage.attr({src: $(this) ????
        // Remove loader
        res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
    }
});
});
});
```

Html:

```
<body>
<div class="galleryContainer">
<img src="images/bella-sky-hotel-1.jpg" id="mainImage" />
</div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is the ajax call just getting the image itself or from a data source?

Comment: @MarkS hmmm I guess my thought was to getting the data source!? Or could I just load lines of img tag from a php-file?

Comment: Your url would be the webpage you generate the image from. what's in data? If you're just getting the image as the url (whatever.jpg), instead of ajax use the jquery load function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you!? I want to load the data of the image

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

 var res = {
loader: $('<div />', {class: 'loader'}),
container: $('.galleryContainer')
}

var img = $("#mainImage");

$("#menu ul li a").click(function() {

var btnNum = $("a").index(this)+1;//because 0 based
var imgFile = "images/bella-sky-hotel-" + btnNum + ".jpg";

    res.container.append(res.loader);// Change src of current image
    mainImage.attr({src: imgFile})
    // Remove loader
    res.container.find(res.loader).remove();

 });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but is this really loading the data of images? Or how does it work?

Comment: so you want to getImageData and then do what with? Answer my question then I will edit my answer.

I think you have to download this data as a `string.` It is simple so use `Ajax` to load a server side string. You server side url must be able to return you a string that represente a real image data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm learning jQuery and I don't know how all this stuff work! I just want to create some kind of script to show a spinner animations while a large image is loading after a user have clicked on a button. I think it would be good to show a spinner animation when website is on mobile devices. User clicks on a button, but nothing seems to happen due to the extra loading time. Right know I'm trying to build a simple script with jQuery .load(), I guess it will work, but when I read on the jQuery page, it has some problems. Ajax like the code above would be better?